# Which character is ’?

Tags: support

I have had a post of mine edited, where words like *doesn't* and *it's* were replaced by *doesn’t* and *it’s*. The new apostrophe is not *'* (the same button as *"*) and it is not *`* (the same button as *~*). I've looked on my keyboard for other characters that look like an apostrophe, but I could find any; the comma looks like it, but it is on the bottom of the line.

What character is it, and how is it typed?

Comment: I was wondering why somebody would ask about a charwoman, or a tea  on meta. `;)` (Those are two of the meaning of _char_, in British English.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [Unicode Character 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm)

You can type them on a Mac by typing `Shift+Option+]`
You can type them on Windows by typing Alt+0146

More details [here](http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/finetypography/ht/curly_quotes.htm)

Comment: In SE answers, you can also use `&rsquo;` along with other HTML entities.

Comment: It æworksÆ (just checking! :). So there you have it - that Alt/digits business *doesn't* work on *my* Windows XP system running Google Chrome.

Comment: ... but ‘cut & paste’ works! (I “think”).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: For the alt-num shortcuts, you need to type the numbers on the numeric keypad (for which you naturally have to have NumLock on). On a laptop without a full keyboard, this can be difficult, in which case there's always the Character Map utility. Or copy & paste, as you said.

Comment: @Martha: As a programmer, I've used *Alt + (tap out a number)* for decades, but I've never noticed NumLock status being relevant. On my system, NumLock makes no difference whatsoever if I'm in, say, a simple text editor like Notepad. If I'm typing into an ELU input box then, for example, Alt/65 works normally and generates an **A** with NumLock *off*. But everything goes screwy in unpredictable ways throughout the Google Chrome browser if I have NumLock on.

Comment: @FumbleFingers One problem with those Windoze numbers is that there is no possible mnemonic for them.  A second problem is that it takes four keys instead of one.  A third and fatalizing problem is that ***those are not even the Unicode numeric code points***, which is just pure nuttery-buggery.

Comment: @tchrist: A ***fourth*** problem (which probably doesn't affect many people other than myself) is that because you can only do it using the *left* Alt key, it's impossible to do it with only one hand. I've always done 99.9% of my typing using just two fingers of my right hand - but I just can't reach that far across. So I either have to drag the atrophied left arm/hand into play, or fiddle about for ages with the mouse and find something suitable for cut&paste.

Comment: @tchrist: I believe the alt-num codes predate Unicode.